# Jmeter - Beanshell script to read a text file parse it for keyword .e.g (start) and get correspomsing timestamp from text file

Tags: parsing, text, jmeter, timestamp, beanshell

I am getting the logs runtime in jmeter and saving it to text file for further processing.
I need to parse the text file for specific keywords like start and stop and get the equivalent timestamp from the text file, then get the difference between them to get the time for processing an operation.

Can anyone let me know how this can be done using Beanshell scripting in Jmeter. Or is there any other better way for the above requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended to avoid scripting where possible so first of all try using built-in JMeter components, like:

- [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) - to read the file into a JMeter Variable
- [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) - to extract "start" and "end" timestamps
- [__longSum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__longSum) - to get the delta between start and end time

---

If you have to go for scripting consider using the most performing option which is [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black).

Answer (score 1):

In JMeter 3.3 you have new function [__timeShift](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__timeShift) which return current time,

You can use to save in start variable: `${__timeShift(,,,,start)}`

And then save stop variable `${__timeShift(,,,,stop)}`

And then use scripting for example for calculate differences e.g. `${__groovy(${stop} - ${start})}`

Comment: No need to wait for JMeter 3.3; there's already [__time](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__timeShift) since 2.2 that does exactly this, as `${__timeShift(,start)}`and `${__timeShift(,start)}`. `__timeShift`returns current time PLUS extra offset, hence its name.